# What does the "activate fan" button do?

Tags: destiny

In the Tower, in the catwalk area above Eris, there is a button that says activate fan. But, when I press it, nothing happens. What does this button do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On top of the Post Office, there is a fan, that when activated by pressing this button, will turn on. If another player is standing on the fan, it will launch them into the air.

Comment: I was guessing it had something to do with that, but I had no one who could help me confirm anything.

Comment: It has been used by players to boost to the top of the vaults.

Answer (score 0):

The building in the middle has a fan on top. It, well, activates that fan.

The circular one; the shack.

Comment: Does that cause anything in particular things that happen when you press it?

Comment: @ShadowZ. If someone/something is on top of the fan, they get pushed into the air. [Fun :)](https://youtu.be/f4yiVhCjDss)